Compositor not using GPU
I have GPU/Full enabled in compositing but it doesn't work. Compositing is still using CPU. Any thoughts how to fix this. CPU is very slow in compositing.

What settings are you refering to ? How do you know GPU isn't used ?

In the compositing sidebar under options - performance you can set GPU or CPU. I know because I have HWinfo enabled and GPU CUDA stays at 0 while the CPU is working. Can also hear CPU fans when compositing.
